# Suggestions required for generating this logging file structure in django project

Tags: python, django, logging

Can anyone please suggest how to generate log files having following directory-file structure using python logging in django project.

```
logs/2009-03-09 
          /errors.log
          /warnings.log
          /info.log
          /emails.log
          /messages.log

logs/2009-03-08 
          /errors.log
          /warnings.log
          /info.log
          /emails.log
          /messages.log
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Set up `FileHandler` instances with `Filter` instances which match the criteria for those files.
2. Add the handlers to the root logger.
3. Profit ;-)

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams) for an example of a filter which matches a specific level. You can use that as an example to create your own custom filters for 'emails' and 'messages' logs.

Use `strftime` to format the paths with dates in them.