# Best practices for logging in django project

Tags: python, django, logging

It is always good to utilize existing patterns for solving the given problem rather then reinventing the wheel. This time it is about doing logging stuffs in django based project.

Can you please share your ideas with me and other about how do you prefer to implement logging in django based project in the following context?

- What factors would you consider before starting design of logging system?
- What would you like to log in a project? (messages, errors, request etc)?
- How would you like to log?
- What should be directory structure?
- In what format would you like to log?
- Which django apps do you use?
- Have you make any such reusable apps? if yes, can you share with other?
- Or any other idea which you find useful to share with other.

**... Any little help would be really good for all django developers ...**

cheers

Comment: Why aren't you just using the built-in `logging` module?  What all the detailed questions?

Answer (score 7):

In Django, like in any other Python application, I'd use the standard library's [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging) module and call `logging.debug`, `logging.info` etc as appropriate to each message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex, I asked a question earlier

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408800/suggestions-required-for-generating-this-logging-file-structure-in-django-project

But not one replied so I thought if everyone share a little about logging this post will have lots of useful information about the subject...

Comment: @Software Enthusiastic: "But not one replied"  False.