# Python - Logging and levels

Tags: python, logging

I use python module `logging` to generate log files and console print.
I set up my script to log all errors levels, without DEBUG to file.
But i have trouble with set up handler for console printing. On console i want to display level `INFO` and **below**, not up like `setLevel` doing. Is any way to do this with *inline* code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams might be help full.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "inline code", but you can achieve this using Filters.

```
class InfoAndLower(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.levelno <= logging.INFO
```

and then attach a filter instance to your console handler.

```
h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
h.addFilter(InfoAndLower())
```

In Python 3.2 and later, you don't need to create a class - a callable will do:

```
h.addFilter(lambda record: record.levelno <= logging.INFO)
```