# How to write to log in python with nginx + uwsgi

Tags: python, logging, nginx, uwsgi

I have a server running nginx + UWSGI + python. UWSGI is running as a daemon with the flag set: `--daemonize /var/log/uwsgi.log` which logs all application errors.

I've noticed that on error if I use a python print statement it will write to the log but only on an error. The standard python logging library doesn't seem to affect the log in any situation.

How do I point the python logging libraries to use the UWSGI log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use logging.StreamHandler as logging handler

Comment: Although your answer was not detailed, it led me down the right path. This answer describes the method I used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams

Comment: @elkelk: Could you extend? I don't need the filters and tried to log with this method - it still doesn't print anything into the file.

Comment: I have similar problem but in regards with Docker containers. Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511839/how-to-force-applications-stdout-logs-through-uwsgi

Answer (score 5):

uWSGI is a wsgi server, and as such passes a stream in the `environ` dict passed to the application callable it hosts, using the key `wsgi.errors`.  If you are writing a bare wsgi app, then writing to that stream should do the job.  If you are using a framework that abstracts the wsgi interface out (and by the sound of it, you are, `print` would ordinarily write to `sys.stdout`, which gets closed on a daemonized process and would never make it to any log file), you will probably need to look into how that framework handles error logging.