# How to force application's stdout logs through uwsgi?

Tags: django, logging, nginx, docker, uwsgi

I have Django application running behind `uwsgi` inside Docker container. `uwsgi` is started via `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` parameters in Dockerfile. I succesfully connect it to separated Nginx container and check expected results in browser.

So far, so good.

Now I would like see application logs in Django container. But I am not able to find right combination of Django's settings `LOGGING` variable and `uwsgi` switches. I just see `uwsgi` standard logs which is useless for me.

Is it possible at all? It seems to me, that I must make some wrapper BASH script, like:

````
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:80 --die-on-term --module myapp.wsgi:application --chdir /src --daemonize /dev/null
tail -f /common.log```
````

... set `LOGGING` inside Django to write into `/common.log` and tail it to output.

Is there some more elegant solution?

**Updated 2016-02-24:**

Yes, it is possible. I made mistake somewhere in my first tests. I published working example on https://github.com/msgre/uwsgi_logging.

Comment: What `LOGGING` options have you tried?

Comment: Basically `StreamHandler`, to stdout and also stderr. I check it with `manage.py runserver`, logs are visible (on stdout). When I run `uwsgi` behind, I see just uwsgi logs...

    'handlers': {
        'common': {
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'stream': sys.stderr,  # and sys.stdout also
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },

Answer (score 5):

use

> log-master=true

in your uwsgi-conf.ini
or

> --log-master

if you pass it as param

Comment: YES !!! Thank you! Where did you find this info? What does it do? I should say for me, using Flask, it only works if I use `app.logger` and not any `logging.logger`