# Logging only info level entries to a separate file

Tags: python, logging

So I'm using python's built in logging module to perform logging.  In general, I really like the way it works but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do the following:

I want to log data out to a file and console as my script is executing, preferably using logger.info().  I would also like to log warnings/errors out to the console, preferably using logger.warning() and logger.error().  That part is easy.  However, I would also like if the warnings/errors did not also go to the info log.

Right now from my understanding, if I have a handler set at the info level, it will always pass anything at the info level and higher.

The only solution I can think of is to separate my logging to two separate loggers but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Although I did do searching before asking, I actually found my answer in this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams


(If there is an appropriate way to mark this, will someone let me know? Thanks!)

Comment: Add your answer as an answer rather than as a comment, and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the cleaner approach would be to process log messages differently in handler, based on the levels of log records. `LogRecord` objects have `levelno` and `levelname` properties, so you have pretty much everything you need to distinguish `logging.error()` from `logging.warning()` and `logging.debug()`.

More details: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects

Comment: does that mean I would need to create my own loging handler?

Comment: @MattyP: Not necessarily. You can use existing handlers (one for each method of logging) and add different filters to them. Answering the question you may have ("_do I need to create my own filter?_"): it depends - any instance with `filter` method will do (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#filter-objects), you just need to find some suitable existing filter :)