# Python Flask writes access log to STDERR

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Flask is writing access logs to STDERR stream instead of STDOUT. How to change this configuration so that access logs go to STDOUT and application errors to STDERR?

```
open-cricket [master] python3 flaskr.py > stdout.log 2> stderr.log &
[1] 11929

open-cricket [master] tail -f stderr.log
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:9001/
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2015 16:23:25] "GET /?search=Sachin+Tendulkar+stats HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2015 16:23:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume you're using the flask development server.

Flask's development server is based on [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), whose `WSGIRequestHandler` is, in turn, based in the [`BaseHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) on the standard lib.

As you'll notice, [`WSGIRequestHandler` overrides the logging methods](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/50a93a3a01a705200941dab99425cc7cc0fe3454/werkzeug/serving.py#L255), `log_request`, `log_error` and `log_message`, to use it's own `logging.Logger` - so you can simply override it as you wish, in the spirit of IJade's answer.

If you go down that route, I think it'd be cleaner to add your own [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) instead, and [split the stdout and stderr output using a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams)

Note, however, that all this is very implementation specific - **there's really no proper interface to do what you want**.

Although it's tangential to your actual question, I feel I really must ask - **why are you worried about what goes into each log on a development server**?

If you're bumping into this kind of problem, **shouldn't you be running a real web server already**?

Comment: how do you differentiate development/production in Flask?

Comment: @emaillenin as you'd differentiate them in any other piece of software (which is a very broad question). Basically, if it's exposed to anyone but developers and internal quality control, it's production, I'd say.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you got to do. [Import logging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/errorhandling/) and set the level which you need to log.

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I interpreted the question as "how to have access logs on STDOUT?"

Comment: agree with @goncalopp OP's question was how to separate the logs, not how to suppress them.