# python stream handler for multiple servers

Tags: python, logging

There are servers running in multiple locations,I need to stream the application log data from these servers to a **ZMQ**(Zero Message Queue) using **python stream handler**.How do i use the stream handler to get this done? I have already referred the Python Handlers documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler

Answer (score 1):

You can post your logs from different servers as `json` to the ZMQ iteratively. For the ZMQ make a PyZMQ application which will have a message handler, listening to your incoming json from these servers. Then as per requirement the incoming json data can be processed and stored in a file (or wherever you want to store). This file can be read for the incoming logs ( eg: tail -f fileName.txt or fileName.log)

Here is link which will help you setup a PyZMQ application:

[Designing and Testing PyZMQ Applications – Part 1](https://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/2012/02/01/designing-and-testing-pyzmq-applications-part-1/)

For logging specifically you can use these example:

[A simple Python logging example](http://www.mglerner.com/blog/?p=8)

[Logging, StreamHandler and standard streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383254/logging-streamhandler-and-standard-streams?rq=1)